# Remove accent characters in twig

Tags: php, twig

please how I can remove the accent in variable  url 
for example Téléphone to Telephone

```
 <td><a href="{{ path('search_city',{'cityName':url  }) }}">{{ city }}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `iconv` with transliteration activated.

Create a filter with

```
$remove_accent = new Twig_SimpleFilter('remove_accent', function ($string) {
    return iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
});
```

and add it to your Twig environment with

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($remove_accent); // add this
```

then call it in your twig file with

```
{{ city | remove_accent }}
```

Comment: variable $loader not found  ?

Comment: just add `$twig->addFilter($remove_accent);` to your current `Twig_Environment` object

Comment: please how I can access to file of Twig environment

Comment: read the documentation, http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation, http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

Answer (score 6):

Alternative method :

```
    <td><a href="{{ path('search_city',{'cityName':url  }) | replace({ 'á':'a', 'é':'e', 'í':'i', 'ó':'o', 'ú':'u' }) }}">{{ city }}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace accents individually, without the need for a custom filter

```
city|replace({'à':'a'})|replace({'é':'e'})
```